# Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, exception

I get such error while run a project in flutter. Why is this happening and how can I fix this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1581)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1476)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1483)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1288)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1251)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:732)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:849)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Why is this happening?**

=>
The error is related to Gradle, it is usually caused by a corrupt or incomplete Gradle setup

## **how to fix this error?**

**For mac user:**
open terminal and execute

> cd ~

> rm -rf .gradle

**For windows user:**

Go to the root directory C:\Users\YourUser and locate the hidden .gradle folder and delete it.
and then run your app connected to an Android emulator or device, don't cancel and make have a stable internet connection, this will download fresh Gradle

Comment: rm: .gradle: Permission denied

Comment: Try using sudo along with the command.

Answer (score 0):

in my case firstly I open an android folder

android>gradel>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties

in gradle-wrapper.properties change

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

```
                                to
```

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip

Comment: and then after invalid cache and restart

Answer (score 0):

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.ducafecat.woo_commerce.flutter_woo_commerce_getx_learn"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs. 
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
    // minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    minSdkVersion 21
    // targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion 33   // change this 31 to 33
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue using Flutter

```
    Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
[        ] > java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
```

For some reasons this only happens when building a release but generating a debug apk works fine.

I tried everything about downloading gradle manually nothing works.
Flutter suggests this fix:

```
[!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.            │ To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.       To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
```

However, when I compile with --no-shrink it seems that the directive is being ignored.

I have this in my build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions will greatly help